# Classcastexception with itself in jpacontroller

Tags: jpa, glassfish, classcastexception

I have a web application on glassfish which includes some database calls built with JPA. Whenever I re-deploy the web app, however, I get a ClassCastException com.item.DBItem cannot be cast to com.item.DBItem when I try to retrieve an item.

```
public DBItem findActiveItemId(String itemid){
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try{
            Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c from DBItems c WHERE c.itemId = :cid AND c.active = 1");
            q.setParameter("cid", itemid);
            return (DBItem)q.getSingleResult();
        }catch(javax.persistence.NoResultException nre){
            return null;
        }finally{
            em.close();
        }        
    }
```

Restarting glassfish consistently solves the issue, but why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: this kind of errors usually come up when you have a JAR file duplicated at different levels of the classpath hierarchy. Did you check that the JAR file that contains the class `com.item.DBItem` is not duplicated inside Glassfish domain's `lib` folder and inside your webapp `lib` folder?